# How to define a function that must be resolved before any component is rendered?

Tags: angular

I'm building a webapp using Angular 7 and AWS serverless stack.

A user can be authorized or anonymous, and I need to set AWS credentials accordingly *before* any component is rendered.

In other words: I need this function to run:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';

// Sets AWS credentials for authorized or anonymous user
async updateAWSCredentials() {
  const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
  AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
  AWS.config.credentials = Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials);
}
```

**Question:** How can I define functionality that will run at bootstrap and resolve *before* any component is rendered?

Please note: Having this functionality in the `ngOnInit` of app.component is not a workable solution, since [route resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) is executed in parallel to this function.

Comment: Are both AWS and Auth injected services?

Comment: They are imported like this: import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

Comment: Question has now been edited to include the answer to your question.

Comment: you need to use Route Guards https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication. The guard will only navigate to the components once the conditions set have been met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) for this purpose. See [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-app-initializer-token-to-hook-into) to find out more

Answer (score 1):

You could place the logic in `main.ts` if you truly want it executing before anything else.

```
(async () => {
    const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
    AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
    AWS.config.credentials = Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials);

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
})();
```

You could also execute the code in the `AppModule` constructor.

I'd argue that this code should be wrapped and managed in a service that is responsible for managing the credentials and loading them if they're outdated or not present which can then be consumed in a route guard, and elsewhere in the app when required.

```
@Injectable()
export class AwsAuthService {
  IsAuthenticated() {
     return AWS.config.credentials != null;
  }
  async updateAWSCredentials() {
    const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
    AWS.config.region = 'eu-central-1';
    AWS.config.credentials = Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials);
  }
}

 @Injectable()
 export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public authentication: AwsAuthService){}

     canActivate() {
         if (this.authentication.IsAuthenticated()) {
          //continue as normal
         }else{
         //load creds
         }

     }

 }
```